# Using DataGridRowEventArgs in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, events

I have a DataGrid and I want to scroll automatic to my last row, when the user added rows. My Solution is, that i use the LoadingRow event. But my Problem is, that I don't know, how i use my datagrid in the event.

XAML Code:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LoadingRow">
                <cmd:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadingRowCommand}"></cmd:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel-Constructor:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LoadingRowCommand = new DelegateCommand<DataGridRowEventArgs(LoadingRow, CanExecute);
    }
```

LoadingRowEvent in ViewModel:

```
    public DelegateCommand<DataGridRowEventArgs> LoadingRowCommand { get; set; }

    private bool CanExecute(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void LoadingRow(DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentRow = e.Row.Item;
        datagrid.ScrollIntoView(currentRow); // <- here is my Problem, how do get my datagrid?
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to use CodeBehind you can write an AttachedProperty for that. Let me know if I should build you a detailed example

Comment: @Tomtom Thank you for your answer! Can you write a example? I have never worked with AttachedProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attachedproperty looks like

```
 namespace WPFGridLoadingRow
 {
 public class DataGridExtension
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowLoadedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RowLoadedCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(DataGridExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnRowLoadedcommandChanged));

        private static void OnRowLoadedcommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null)
                return;

            if (e.NewValue is ICommand)
            {
                dataGrid.LoadingRow += DataGridOnLoadingRow;
            }
        }

        private static void DataGridOnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null)
                return;


            ICommand rowLoadedCommand = GetRowLoadedCommand(dataGrid);
            rowLoadedCommand.Execute(e.Row.Item);
            // you can also pass the complete row. Or you move your complete ui-logic here to this attached property.
        }

        public static void SetRowLoadedCommand(DependencyObject element, ICommand value)
        {
            element.SetValue(RowLoadedCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static ICommand GetRowLoadedCommand(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (ICommand)element.GetValue(RowLoadedCommandProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

View.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFGridLoadingRow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFGridLoadingRow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VM x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Name="dgGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" local:DataGridExtension.RowLoadedCommand="{Binding RowLoadedCommand}" >
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}" Grid.Row="1" >
        Add row
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace WPFGridLoadingRow
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class VM: ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyLong> ItemsSource { get; set; }
        public VM()
        {
            ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyLong>();
            AddRowCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddRow);
            RowLoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(RowLoaded);
        }

        public void RowLoaded(object currentRow)
        {
            // currentRow now is the same as e.Row.Item
        }

        public DelegateCommand AddRowCommand { get; set; }

        private void AddRow()
        {
            ItemsSource.Add(new MyLong { Value = 333L });
        }

        public DelegateCommand<object> RowLoadedCommand { get; set; }
    }

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class MyLong
    {
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does removes the code from the code behind, but You still don't have the reference to the DataGrid in the VM (which is good). `ICommand rowLoadedCommand = GetRowLoadedCommand(dataGrid);
            rowLoadedCommand.Execute(e.Row.Item);` should be just `dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Row.Item)` without command. The DependencyProperty's type should be just bool or something.

Comment: @ntohl Yes, it's right! But how does look my xaml code? Where I should invoke my AttachedProperty?

Comment: @A.H AttachedProperty is used in this part of the xaml: `local:DataGridExtension.RowLoadedCommand="{Binding RowLoadedCommand}"`. What happens here, that the DataGrid gains a new Custom Property named RowLoadedCommand. It have the type ICommand. `OnRowLoadedcommandChanged` runs when this property is set. Are You interested in this "invoke"? When You set the command for this property, the command will be invoked in the `rowLoadedCommand.Execute(e.Row.Item);` row.

Comment: @ntohl I have set a breakpoint to my AttachedProperty. He jumps just once, otherwise nothing happens. :(

Comment: @A.H On which line is the breakpoint? The example as is does not scrolls into view.

Comment: @ The Breakpoint is on line where i declare the RowLoadedCommandProperty. The event and the rest are not invoked.

Comment: I guess the local:DataGridExtension.RowLoadedCommand="{Binding RowLoadedCommand}" is missing from the DataGrid from the xaml.

Comment: No, the line in the xaml I have not forgotten. :/

Comment: Than at least `DataGrid dataGrid = d as DataGrid;` should be reached. It happens when You set that property.

Comment: I have fix my Problem! The Name from the binding and the AttachedProperty should not be the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to take in to consideration what belongs to ViewModel, and what belongs to View. We should be able to switch the whole View class (`MainWindow`) below from the ViewModel without a problem, and create an UWP view for the same `VM` ViewModel. In UWP there is not even a DataGrid. How would You call `datagrid.ScrollIntoView` in the ViewModel?

`ScrollIntoView` belongs to the view, that's why it is ok to write code in the code behind.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFGridLoadingRow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFGridLoadingRow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:VM x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Name="dgGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" >
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}" Grid.Row="1" >
        Add row
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

You are very much right, that there should be no business logic specific code in the code behind here. If there is `((VM)(DataContext).XY` in the code, it is a good indicator, that something is wrong, or some binding is missing.

```
namespace WPFGridLoadingRow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            dgGrid.ScrollIntoView(e.Row.Item);
        }
    }
}
```

VM.cs (`ImplementPropertyChanged` coming from [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged))

```
namespace WPFGridLoadingRow
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class VM: ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyLong> ItemsSource { get; set; }
        public VM()
        {
            ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyLong>();
            AddRowCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddRow);
        }

        public DelegateCommand AddRowCommand { get; set; }

        private void AddRow()
        {
            ItemsSource.Add(new MyLong { Value = 333L });
        }
    }

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class MyLong
    {
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to use the MVVM pattern, the code-behind i don't want to use.

Comment: It isn't against MVVM to use View for what it is. VM should care about VM stuff. If You want to exchange the view below the ViewModel, than for example using a mobile view, You have to reimplement the code, that will `ScrollIntoView` the last row. It's view specific, and I doubt that there is `ScrollIntoView` in every possible mobile UI framework

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly. The ScrollInto works for my case, because I have already written it in the code-behind. But I have made it back again because I wanted to write it in the ViewModel.

Comment: I mean it's ok to have code-behind in the view, which is UI specific (in this case `ScrollIntoView`). In fact I would rule out to have UI specific using in the VM.

Comment: @A.H I have elaborated with example my oppinion.

Comment: Thank you for your example!