# WPF MVVM combobox in grid change individual background

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, background

I have CustomGrid with two columns. In each column there is a combobox populated with items list (which are custom objects). The number of rows (by row i understand these two comboboxes side by side, each in separated column) can be added dynamically.
The problem is that, how can i change background for each row (both comboboxes) individually, based on SelectedItem in first combobox?

```
<CustomGrid:CustomDataGrid x:Name="mainCustomGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceList,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                SelectedRowItem="{Binding SelectedItemSource,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Tag="{Binding SelectedItem}" SelectionMode="Extended" >

                        <DataGrid.Columns>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="firstComboBox"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SomeTypesList}" 
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                                                  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayValue" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <ComboBox x:Name="secondComboBox"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SomeValuesList}" 
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
                                                  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayValue" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                    </CustomGrid:CustomDataGrid>
```

I tried playing with styles and data triggers, but changes were applied for all rows and i want to treat them individually

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: First please check that your grid row (CustomDataGrid.Rows[i]) has Background property. Next find grid events like LoadingRow, AddingRow and try from these events (codebehind) that background changing is working as expected. After it works as you need, you can move events from codebehing to triggers by using attached behavior properties ([Using DataGridRowEventArgs in WPF/MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341902/using-datagridroweventargs-in-wpf-mvvm)) and interaction triggers from System.Windows.Interactivity (https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/how-to-use-interaction-triggers-to-handle-user-initiated-events-in-wpf-mvvm/)